# display message after php post jquery, disable redirect

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

So, following some advice earlier I wanted to create a email form where after you submit a valid e-mail the signup box disappears and a new message appears saying 'Thanks for signing up' or something along those lines. I got the validation down. And my process.php works. Also, #message gets hidden, but the page redirects right afterwards and in the address bar it shows: www.myurl.com/?address=wahteveriinputed@whatever.com

Here is my jquery code regarding the posting:

```
function stateChanged3 () {

}

function GetXmlHttpObject () {
    var requestObj = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        requestObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        requestObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        return requestObj;
    }
    requestObj3 = GetXmlHttpObject();
    var url = "mlml/process.php?address=" + emailaddressVal;
    requestObj3.open("POST", url, true);
    requestObj3.onreadystatechange = stateChanged3;
    requestObj3.send(null);
    $('#message').toggle();
```

my php code is pretty simple it's a modified open source mailer is as follows:

```
$email = $_REQUEST["address"];
$key = md5(time());
$req_time = time();
$query = "SELECT * FROM `mailinglist_subscribers` WHERE `address` = '$email'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows != 1) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO mailinglist_subscribers VALUES ('$email', '$key', '1', '$req_time', '0')";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: holy cow! Why aren't you using jQuery for the ajax request? Also, there's not enough code info to fully understand what's going on. Are you clicking a link, a button? Which action does your form perform?

Comment: i click a button. i would prefer it to be a link but I haven't figured out a way to do that. Then when I click the button it runs through validation checks using my jquery script then if it passes it runs the 1st set of code. which posts for the 2nd set of code (which is process.php).... make sense?

Comment: Am I right to assume that your form element uses the method "GET" and the action "#"? What is the javascript function that gets executed once you click the button? Does it `return false` to prevent the form from being submitted?

Comment: @mrtsherman so sorry i didnt' realize i could accept correct answers!

Comment: Solved it! I wasn't returning false and i didn't set action to "#" THANKS i'm an idiot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- use a javascript library (like jquery to do the ajax call), it would make your life easier.
- use onclick, or tap to click event, not stateChanged event, and return false in the event handler.
- set the callback for the ajax call to do things like: hide signup box and show new message.

Comment: i'm using ajax now specifically this code: 'var datastring = "address=" + emailaddressVal;
        $.ajax({type : "POST",
            url : "mlml/process.php",
            data : datastring,
            success : function() {
                alert("something");
            } 
        });'  the alert is not showing up

Comment: try this: $.get('mlml/process.php?address='+ emailaddressVal, function(data) {
  alert('something');
}); Make sure 'mlml/process.php' is the correct path and log on the PHP side to make sure it does execute.